# Using VisualPHPUnit with newest PHAR version of phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

Has anyone managed to get `VisualPHPUnit` to work with `PHPUnit 4.x` (installed via the newer PHAR package) and has some directions for me?

All instructions I find are referencing to older installation methods like PEAR or Composer which are all deprecated.

Comment: What have you tried that does not work? Error messages? Asking for off-line resources is off-topic here.

Comment: I tried to substitute in the files `app/config/bootstrap.php` the two rows require_once of PHPUnit with the line `require_once '/<path-of-my-project>/vendor/autoload.php';` but no lucky yet

Comment: Every instruction that you can find, states that you have to change the settings `pear_path` and `test_directories` in `app/config/bootstrap.php` and then it should work. But this won't work with the PHAR package - resulting in error messages stating that some include references could not be loaded. Some instructions also try to change the `set_include_path` line in the lower section of the config file to include the PHPUnit directory. But there's no such thing as a PHPUnit directory when using PHAR. Also there's always the reference to Autoload, which i read is not used anymore in 4.x .